# Integrate an API into a vb.net service app to execute

Tags: vb.net, service

I have a vb.net service app running on a work network server, which runs a job on a repeating timer. I'd like to be able to call an API to tell this service to run, possibly with input parameters, but I can't seem to search for the right thing to get started on this.

I'm not looking for a full explanation on how to do it (unless someone's feeling very generous), but rather tips on where to look, what to search for, or if it's even possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a online search enginge to search for `vb.net windows service api`
2. Pick an entry like [Tutorial: Create a Windows service app | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer)
3. Read and stumble upon ServiceController
4. Profit!

Comment: This answer should never have been posted because this question should never have been posted.

Comment: @jmcilhinney You're right, I should have a minimum coffee-level before posting ;)

Comment: @DavidSdot Thanks for the help, and for not being a twat.